# Best ways to initialize a PostgreSQL RDS in AWS for the first time

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am building an application in AWS using these services for the backend and database:

- ECS / Fargate with an Application Load Balancer. This uses a Java Spring Boot API running in a container.
- RDS using Postgres for the Spring Boot to communicate with.

I have cloudformation scripts to deploy the respective stacks, however, I'm after some guidance on the best ways to run these types of DB commands to initialize it for the first time. This [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/managing-postgresql-users-and-roles/) gives a good overview of the broader considerations.

- create the Postgres DB,
- revoke public schema,
- create roles,
- create schemas,
- change privileges,
- grant usages on schema,
- add extensions etc.

All of this is straightforward to do locally in a tool such as psql or DataGrip from JetBrains.  However, if my database is not publicly accessible then what is the recommended approach?

A few options I considered were:

1. A bastion server but I don't need this for anything else and it seems like overkill.
2. AWS Cloudshell but I believe the DB needs to be publicly accessible.
3. Make the DB publicly accessible, run the scripts and then revert the change.

Comment: Run the psql script (or whatever) from the application container or from a lambda that is invoked as part of the cloudformation stack.

Comment: @Bergi - I think that's a good approach and it should be the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Bergi in the comments, running a script from a lambda or the application container makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently seen the use of InitContainers in several implementations. They live short, can be created for each feature service, and interestingly (since they are independent of their feature service container) do not warrant bringing down feature service if you have to make changes in DB that do not require changes in feature service code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).